# create multiple array from an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array which store some data inside it. Inside the array there will be some data like this

```
Alluser[0] = John || 20 || Student;

Alluser[1] = Will || 19 || Student;
```

I wanted to split the data and arrange one user into one array. Something like this

```
 user0[0] = John;
 user0[1] = 20;
 user0[2] = Student;
```

The number of user will constantly increase later on. But I don't know how to constantly create new array for new user.
I tried something like this

```
for(int i=0;i<Alluser.length;i++){
      String[] user[i]= Alluser[i].split("||");
}
```

I knew that String[] user[i] is wrong, I just don't really the structure of the correct way of handling this issue. Any comment and answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should create a class `User` and store instances in a `List<User>`.

Comment: Did you hear about object-oriented programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OOP:

Create a `class User` and store `List<User> listOfUsers;`

In this case you'll have a list of users and get access to each item, delete it or add new users.

```
class User{
    String name;
    int age;
    ...
}
```

and also you can iterate:

```
for (User eachUser: listOfUsers){
    eachUser.getName();
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need an array that needs to increase in size, consider [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It is a resizable list that internally is structured like an array.

Additionally your `for` loop wont work because the array defined there wont be accessible from outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the split available, use it to your advantage!

```
String[] user = getContent[i].split("||");
```

That will set the user array to contain, for example: "John ", " 19 ", " Student".

As you can see, there are spacing issues, so use the String " || " instead for the split.

Now, to store this outside, do something that follows:

```
String data = new String[getContent.length][3];
```

With that, you can then throw in the 'split' into data[i].